# image restoration，CT scan，closed curve，

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, 2d

There's a problem maybe about digital image.
Actually I don't how to describe the problem before i can google it.
So i am asking some kind of concept in some scientific fields can describe this problem.

CT image，section scan:
[image: img]

This is a section scan of a physical porous material,and this is about civil engineering.
The white part of the image is solid , while the black part is hole.
The cross-section of the hole should be a closed curve. 
However ,for some technical reason， the gray-level of the pixel that describe the outline of these hole , become 0 (black)in the bitmap i got.
as you see,

[image: part2]

pixels circled in green should be like those in red with gray-level above 0 ,because here should be a closed curve to describe the hole .

I want to fix these pixel ,but don't know what kind of this problem is.
Are there some classical algorithms for this problem ?

Comment: Then how did you compute the image?

Comment: This is the raw material ,i haven't done anything to this image.

Comment: If the values of the pixels in question are just 0, I think it would be better to ask for an improved raw image than trying to fix it. If it's used for human treatment you certainly won't want to 'fix' a tissue scan, no matter how clever it is.

Comment: i am sorry i forgot to mention that is the scan of a physical material.
i think this is from the weakness of this technique of scan .

Comment: Actually this is about civil engineering, and ，anyway ,thank you for your advice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique you are looking for is called [dilation](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/dilate.htm). There is an example in the opencv library [erosion and dilation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/db/df6/tutorial_erosion_dilatation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use **morphological operators** like **dilatation** but that would lead to much thicker contours making the holes smaller or even fill them fully if too small.

Another way is to find small gaps.

1. **create 2 helper 2D arrays/images**

   they will contain one integer counter per each pixel of input image. So if your image has resolution `xs,ys` then you can try something like:

   ```cpp
   int cx[ys][xs]; // x direction counter
   int cy[ys][xs]; // y direction counter
   ```
2. **compute `cx`**

   so `cx[y][x]` should hold the count of consequent zeros in the image in `x` direction (rows).

   1. clear `cx[][]` with `0`
   2. `for (y=0;y<ys;y++)`
   3. set `x=-1`
   4. find first zero pixel after `x` and call it `x0`
   5. find last  zero pixel from `x0` and call it `x1`
   6. set `cx[y][x0..x1]=x1-x0+1` and `x=x1+1`
   7. loop **#4** while `x<xs`

   Similarly compute `cy[y][x]` for `y` direction (columns).
3. **detect&repair missing contour**

   This is easy if `min(cx[y][x],cy[y][x])<threshold` then pixel `x,y` belongs to missing contour and should be set to white ... The `threshold` value is max length of missing contour and must be smaller then smallest hole size.

So the holes must be bigger then missing contour gaps. Otherwise this would not work. You can improve this by creating another `map` holding black area sizes. (flood fill any black pixel but instead of color use number of filled pixels so you need to apply flood fill 2 times once for counting and once for filling) Then apply missing contour only on areas that are larger than small holes to prevent filling small holes.

There are also another possibilities like detecting the vanishing contour pattern and joining too close such pattern.